# Bind model to custom directive

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I attempt to provide a  model(geography) in the controller as an input to a directive in angularJs1.3 -

index.html

```
<html lang="en" ng-app="directivesApp">
<head>
    <script src="js/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/app.js"></script>
 </head>
<body ng-controller="directiveCtrl">
    <label>Geography</label><input type="text" ng-model="geography"/>
    <custom-Demo user={{geography}}></custom-Demo>
</body>
</html>
```

app.js

```
angular.module('directivesApp', [])
.directive('customDemo',function(){
    return{
        restrict:'E',
        template:'Geography : <b>{{geography}}</b>',
        scope:{geography : '='}
    }
});
```

However,the value entered in the input is not reflected in the html rendered from the directive.
How do I make this happen?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You set `geography` to `user` attribute of your `customDemo` directive. But in your directive there is only `geography` attribute defined in scope.
So replace your code to following:

```
<label>Geography</label><input type="text" ng-model="geography"/>
<custom-Demo geography="geography"></custom-Demo>
```

And pass `geography` variable as object instead of value (without curly braces).

---

Or you can define `geography` variable in your directive likes this:

```
scope: {
      geography : '=user'
}
```

And in your html just remove curly braces from `geography` variable which is passed to `user` attribute of your `customDemo` directive.

```
<label>Geography</label><input type="text" ng-model="geography"/>
<custom-Demo user="geography"></custom-Demo>
```

[See it in plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/eUAWxjrRKuwHFxjgC80a?p=preview)

Answer (score 0):

**DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/softvar/b7Lf5x9r/1/**

Adding `scope: {...}` inside the directive make it an isolated directive. https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive. Also to pass geography's value from the controller to the directive, assign it inside the controller and pass this to directive. Directive can access all scope variables of the controller if it's not an isolated one. If you intend to use `scope: {...}` inside your directive, only the variables you pass to the directive would be available to the directive on its scope. TO access - `scope: {...}, link: function(scope) {console.log(scope)}`.

**JS**:

```
angular.module('directivesApp', [])
.controller('directiveCtrl', function ($scope) {
    $scope.geography = 'IND - Country';
})
.directive('customDemo',function(){
    return{
        restrict:'E',
        template:'Geography : <b>{{geography}}</b>',
        scope: {
            geography: '='
        }
    }
});
```

**HTML**:

```
<label>Geography</label><input type="text" ng-model="geography"/>
<custom-Demo data-geography="geography"></custom-Demo>
```

Comment: I think, that it’s better when you pass all necessary data via attributes of your directive instead of keeping in mind that parent scope contains some variables.
In your example attribute ‘user’ is absolutely unnecessary because it’s never used. Maybe it’s just typo. %)